# Routing Video Feed Through Computer

Tags: hdmi

I received a *Raspberry Pi Model B+* today and went to plug it into my monitor. Unfortunately, my monitor does not have a HDMI port. It has a DVI port which is currently connected to my home PC. However, my graphics card on my home PC has both a DVI port and an HDMI port. Is it possible to route the video feed from the Pi to my PC (via HDMI) and then from the PC to the monitor (using DVI)?

Thank you,
Dave C

Comment: As per the duplicate question, a normal graphics card does not have external inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Buy a `DVI` to `hdmi` converter. These are simple passive devices and you should be able to get one for less than $10